# Transfer XAP file from one phone (Lumia 920) to another

Tags: windows-phone-8, xap

I received a new Lumia 920 through AT&T's warranty program, and my old phone has a couple key apps that are no longer available for download - Swapchat (a SnapChat client) and Youtube.  How can I copy the XAP files from my old phone and deploy them on the new one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, unless you have a custom unlocked ROM which I doubt. Try Metrotube instead of Youtube and there is no SnapChar client at the moment.

Comment: Actually you can't even do it with custom unlocked ROMs :) The apps are DRM signed, so they *need* to be installed via. the marketplace.